# How to split string with comma but avoid backslash-comma?

Tags: java, regex

I have a following string:

```
 161544476293,26220\,1385853403,WLAN-EneTec5,-85,0,0
```

How to split it with comma but avoid `\,` case.

In my case above mentioned String should be split as:

```
161544476293
26220\,1385853403
WLAN-EneTec5
-85
 0
 0
```

Thanks,

Comment: Just to be clear, why wouldn't `-85`, `0`, and `0` be split apart, too?

Comment: Are there any other escape sequences involved, e.g. does the format use \\ to escape backslashes too?  If you need to ignore \, but still split at \\, then you'll need something more powerful than regular expressions.

Comment: Where is the split in something like this: `161544476293,26220\\,1385853403,WLAN-EneTec5,-85,0,0` ?

Comment: This looks like an unusual csv format. Normally anything escaped in a field is surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
str.split("(?<!\\\\),");

// OUTPUT: "161544476293", "26220\,1385853403", "WLAN-EneTec5", "-85", "0", "0"


(?<!\\\\) Negative Lookbehind - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
\\ matches the character \ literally
, matches the character , literally
```

Comment: As long as you don't have cases of escaped-bacskslashes like `one\\,two` see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21741861/1266906) to a different question

Answer (score 3):

A pattern like this:

```
(?<!\\),
```

Will match any `,` character *not* immediately preceded by a `\` character. Of course, this is Java, so make sure you escape the `\`'s in your string literal:

```
String pattern = "(?<!\\\\),";
```